# How can i get a count of two values using multiple tables inner joins and group by?

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

I have a set of tables and I am trying to get the two counts by state to display.  It's proving to be a little tricky partly because some results will have a count of 0.  I'm not sure how to deal with those at the moment.

First I'll show my table structure and then I'll explain what counts I'm trying to get.  I'm thinking its probably something simple, but I'm a little rusty on sql queries.

Here is how my tables are setup.  I have one primary table that I'm using to join the other tables too.

```
t1 (primary table)
ID, qrtID, sdID, published

t2
qID, qTypes, qSlug

t3
stateID, stateName, stateAbbr
```

The values link like this.  t1.qrtID = t2.qID, t1.sdID = t3.stateID.

The qSlug values has 2 possible values (past and present), so i want to get the counts based on those groups.

What I want to end up with are columns for stateName, qSlug_count1, and qSlug_count2.  If there is a count of "0", i want to display "0".

So for now this is what i got.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT sdID, COUNT(qrtID) AS past_count FROM t1 WHERE qrtID = "1" GROUP BY sdID) c1 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT sdID, COUNT(qrtID) AS pres_count FROM t1 WHERE qrtID = "2" GROUP BY sdID) c2
ON c1.sdID = c2.sdID
```

The results from this query are close to what I need, but i am missing some data.  I need to get the stateName, stateAbbr, and also if there is a count of 0, show a 0 in the column.  So all states should be respresented in the results.

So, the question is how can i modify the query I have above to add in the additional tables and join them to correct values AND also be able to show zero values if there are no records that match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation in a single query:

```
SELECT sdID,
       sum(qrtID = "1") AS past_count
       sum(qrtID = "2") AS pres_count
FROM t1 
GROUP BY sdID;
```

Your query is missing rows because some `sdID`s have only 1's and others have only 2's.  You might want to add:

```
where qrtID in ("1", "2")
```

if you don't want rows where two `0`s could appear.

Comment: I actually want the rows that have a "0" count to appear.  So, how can i join in the other data like the statename and stateabbr to get the counts listed by state.  Would i use an inner join?

Comment: awesome dude...Thanks for your help I got it working!  I must have been overthinking this little problem...I used a two LEFT JOINS to pull in the additional data I needed.